# Functions whose arc length equals the area under the curve

Tags: geometry, analysis

A very nice property of the hyperbolic cosine is that its arc length on an interval $[a,b]$ equals the area enclosed by the graph, the $x$-axis and the lines $x=a$ and $x=b$. That is, the following equation holds: $$\int_a^b f(x)\, dx=\int_a^b \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\, dx $$
The same holds for the constant function $f(x)=1$. Probably, one can obtain other functions satisfying these properties by small modification to the hyperbolic cosine. I was wondering if there is some kind of description of all the functions $f(x)$ satisfying this property, or if there exist more functions than the constant function and the hyperbolic cosine which area equals the arc length.

Comment: Assuming you want this property to hold for all $a,b$, we can differentiate your equation with respect to $b$ to find that $f(x)=\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$ for all $x$. This is an ODE whose solutions are all translates of the hyperbolic cosine, $f(x)=\cosh(x-c)$.

Comment: Are these the only solutions? How does the constant function $f(x)=1$ fit in?

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. The ODE is $y'=\sqrt{y^2-1}$, whose right-hand side is not Lipschitz at $y=1$ [so we lose uniqueness of the solution there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). However, since we have Lipschitz continuity everywhere else, I believe all the solutions are of the form $y=1$ on some (possibly degenerate, possibly unbounded) interval $[a,b]$, surrounded by $\cosh(x-a)$ on $(-\infty,a]$ and $\cosh(x-b)$ on $[b,\infty)$. But I'm not an expert on ODE theory, so I could be wrong.